# Return Score from AutoML PredictResponse Object

Tags: python, google-prediction, automl

I'm trying to pull the score values out of my google automl PredictResponse Object. the object returned from the API looks as follows:

```
payload {
  classification {
    score: 0.989063024521
  }
  display_name: "No"
}
payload {
  classification {
    score: 0.0109369996935
  }
  display_name: "Yes"
}
```

I've gotten close using this:

```
result.payload[1]
```

Which returns:

```
classification {
  score: 0.0109369996935
}
display_name: "Yes"
```

But I still can't get to just the score for a yes or a no.

I've tried using simplejson, but the PredictResponse Object doesn't play nice with that either. Is there a function within the Object I can use to get to the Score for yes and the score for no? Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to your question:

```
result.payload[0].display_name
```

Answer (score 0):

`result.payload[1].classification.score`

Answer (score 0):

You may use the this code

`d = {}`
`for i in range(len(response.payload)):`
`d[response.payload[i].display_name] = response.payload[i].classification.score`

It will provide you a dictionary for all the categories (Yes and No in your case)

Answer (score 0):

```
 predicted_data = []
 for i in range(len(response.payload)):
   predicted_data.append({
        "key": response.payload[i].display_name,
        "value": response.payload[i].classification.score
    })
```

key-value list of payload objects